# Python ReportLab: Center string

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

I'm currently placing a string with:

```
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
        can.setFont('Helvetica-Bold',12) # Change Font, Font-size, etc
        can.drawString(300, 340, row["name"]) # Change position. First number = points from left, secoond = points from bottom
```

I now have the need to center the string, i.e. just give drawstring the height, the string itself must always be centred.

I searched the net, but couldn't find an easy way to do so. Am I overseeing something?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to put your text in a paragraph in that way you can always customize your text in the way you want.

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("paragraph_spacing.pdf",
                        pagesize=letter
                        )
# creating custom stylesheet
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='my_custom_name', fontName="Helvetica-Bold", fontSize=12, leftIndent=200))
# giving alias to the stylesheet
my_style = styles['my_custom_name']
flowables = []
flowables.append(Spacer(0, 0))
# using the stylesheet
flowables.append(Paragraph(row["name"], my_style))
doc.build(flowables)
```

you can use `Spacer(0, height)` to give height and `leftIndent` to mark the center of the width of your document